# Task bar notification area icons dissapeared after update

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, windows-update, icons, notification-area

After the last **windows 8.1 update** my **task bar seems to no longer keeps the icons** in the notification area >>> it keeps hiding them after every reboot

Note: The setting in task bar properties is right as **show icon and notification**.

any suggestions??

Comment: [some solutions here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/notification-area-icons-missing-at-startup-or/54a96d92-35bd-414f-ae34-0f9eb5fe41db)

Comment: which one worked for you?